# matplotlib - imshow spectrogram with custom nonlinear frequency scale in y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram

I have a time-frequency transform which outputs the Fourier coefficients per frequency bin. For example, the spectrogram I have is:

```
transform: torch.Size([4238, 263])
```

4238 is the time frames, and 263 is the frequency bins. I can plot this with imshow as a spectrogram with 4238 time frames, where the y-axis is the 263 discrete frequency bins:
[image]

I also have the frequency in Hz corresponding to each of the 263 points, which are nonlinearly spaced (by the Bark scale), i.e..:

```
[    0.            32.9           42.67268041    52.45663684
    62.25445465    72.06872285    81.90203482    91.75698894 ...
```

If I simply use `extent=[0,22.05]` (denoting 0-22.05 kHz), it linearly distributes the 263 frequency bins across 0-22.05 kHz, which doesn't map to the nonlinear frequency spacing above.

How can I plot the 263 rows of [4238, 263] to the corresponding 263 nonlinearly-spaced Hz frequencies?

**edit** From the comment, pcolormesh did the trick:
[image]

Comment: Use pcolormesh.

Comment: Thanks! If you make it an answer, I'll accept it as best.

Comment: ... there is no data here to make an answer from!  See https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_levels.html